# What is the purpose of React Router's Index Route in helping your component do stuff like onEnter hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I don't get the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md) from React Router below:

> But now Home can't participate in routing, like the onEnter hooks,
>   etc. You render in the same position as Accounts and Statements, so
>   the router allows you to have Home be a first class route component
>   with IndexRoute.

What does he mean by routing here? What is onEnter hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `App` is wrapping other routes, the route that matches the given url is passed to `App` to be rendered via `this.props.children`.  Because of this, you don't get access to react-router's hooks for `Home` if you do render `Home` via a statement such as `{this.props.children || <Home/>}`. One such hook is`onEnter`, which fires off a callback whenever a route is entered.

When you define `Home` as an `IndexRoute`, it is a distinct route that will match whatever route `App` matches.  This way, we don't need the or clause in `App`, we can just render the child route via `{this.props.children}`

Comment: Why won't you get access to react-router's hooks if you rend `Home` through the or statement? Do hooks only work through the top component through App?

Comment: Because the hooks are on the `Route` component.  A `Route` really just wraps your React component (eg. `Home`) and provides extra functionality, like hooks for when routing transitions happen.  If you render it inside of `App`, it won't be wrapped by a `Route`.  The key thing to realize is that all of these hooks are just props to the `Route` components

Comment: All clear see that the route is just a wrapper with extra functionality. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [docs here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#adding-an-index) are a little more straightforward:

> Imagine we'd like to render another component inside of App when the
>   URL is /. Currently, this.props.children inside of App's render method
>   is undefined in this case. **We can use an `<IndexRoute>` to specify a
>   "default" page.**

As far as `onEnter` the [docs here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#enter-and-leave-hooks) are better:

> Routes may also define `onEnter` and `onLeave` hooks that are invoked once
>   a transition has been confirmed. These hooks are useful for various
>   things like requiring auth when a route is entered and saving stuff to
>   persistent storage before a route unmounts.

Comment: is the route happening every time a component is rendered or just during the first rendering of the parent App component?